# Ubuntu Qmake is not an executable

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

after installing new version of QtCreator in Ubuntu and

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake build-essential g++ gcc
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   build-essential is already the newest version.
   g++ is already the newest version.
   g++ set to manually installed.
   gcc is already the newest version.
   qt5-qmake is already the newest version.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 247 not upgraded.
```

in option of `Build & Run` and choose qmake in `/usr/bin/qmake' i get this error :

```
The qmake executable /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake could not be added: qmake '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake' is not an executable.
```

in Home system i don't have any problem after installing those packages and setting Qmake in option

Other information:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > apt-cache search qt5-qmake
qt5-qmake - Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool

tux-world@alachiq:~ > ldd /opt/qtForArm/bin/qmake 
     ldd: /opt/qtForArm/bin/qmake: No such file or directory

tux-world@alachiq:~ > sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
[sudo] password for tux-world: 
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake’: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**:

after installing Qmake that is under this directory:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > whereis qmake
qmake: /usr/bin/qmake /usr/bin/X11/qmake
```

List Directory on `/usr/sbin`:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > ls -a /usr/sbin/qmake
ls: cannot access /usr/sbin/qmake: No such file or directory
```

Check Executable and other information qmake:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > ls -a -l /usr/bin/qmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 فوریه 19 15:53 /usr/bin/qmake -> qtchooser
```

Comment: After apt-get install, the package is installed under /usr/sbin. Check whether you the qmake executable at this location. Else you can use "whereis" command to check the location of qmake

Comment: @SantoshA UPADTED post, thanks

Comment: You did a `sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake` but right after you try to set the path to a qt4 version ???

Answer (score 6):

my problem is resolved after installing qt5-default:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the updated question it is clear that

> /usr/bin/qmake is a soft link to qtchooser

The error message with the qtchooser is normal, although uninformative. 
 In essence you're trying to execute qtchooser with itself, which doesn't work.

> Run the **$ man qtchooser** command on a terminal for how to use qtchooser

If you are not able to see the man page for **qtchooser** or if the problem persists then I suggest you to install

> **$ sudo apt-get install qt-sdk**

Hope this would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the qmake path to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake. This is where qt5-qmake installs its qmake executable.